# Secure MySQL 8 installation on Ubuntu 20.04 Problem

Tags: mysql

I`m trying to install and configure mysql and phpmyadmin, but after installation mysql-server, when I try to use command mysql_secure_installation terminal ask me to input root password. After entering, it shows ERROR:

```
Securing the MySQL server deployment.
Enter password for user root: 
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I tried install mysql with info from this page https://kifarunix.com/install-mysql-8-on-ubuntu-20-04/

https://www.hivelocity.net/kb/what-to-do-if-mysql-sock-file-is-missing/ That didn`t help

Comment: Several questions on this site refers to that kind of problem.  Did you have a look at those and try some of their solutions? Are you sure that MySQL is up and running?

Comment: Mysql8.0 is not working try steps on this questions accepted answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235829/cant-get-mysql8-to-work-on-ubuntu-20-04